# Quando clico no botão de Link, todo o conteudo da pagina anterior é exibido

Tags: react, react-router, react-router-dom

Estou fazendo um site e preciso clicar em um botão e abrir uma nova pagina e nessa pagina queria que tivesse SOMENTE a section desse component, porem quando eu clico nesse Link, todo o conteudo que tinha na pagina anterior é exibido, fica com duas paginas iguais, sou iniciante com React e estou aprendendo a usar React-router, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Página que contem o Link para ir para outra Página

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CafédeFundo from '../Imagem/Café de Fundo 1.png';
import '../styles/Knowmore.sass'
import {Route, Routes, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import About from '../components/About';

export default class Knowmore extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <>
        <section className='saiba-mais'>
                <img src={CafédeFundo} alt="" />
                <h1>Surpreenda-se</h1>
               <Link to="/About" target={'_blank'} className="btn" type='button'>Conheça</Link>
            </section>
        </>    
      )
 } }
```

Página que eu quero que Seja mostrado somente a section "Saiba-mais" mostrada a cima

```
import React,{Component}from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import {Routes, Route, Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import Knowmore from './Knowmore';

export default function About() {
  return (
    <>
    <div><h1>h1dçsaçdsaçdsa</h1></div>

    <Routes>
    
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route exact path="/About" component={About} />
    
  </Routes>
  </>
  )
}
```

Código do `App.js`

```
const App = () => {     
  return (       
           <>
              <Header />
              <Home />
              <Cardapio />
              <Knowmore />
           </>              
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: por algum motivo os h1 estão sendo renderizados na pergunta, peço desculpas

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente o seu App.js que deveria ter as rotas. Ficando assim:

```
const App = () => {     
  return (       
    <Routes>
      <Route index path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route exact path="/about" element={About} />
      <Route path="*" element={<p>Página não encontrada</p>} />
    </Routes>            
  );
};
export default App;
```

Como o App.js é uma das primeiras coisas a serem renderizadas ele quem irá definir qual a primeira tela que será mostrada. Note que eu adicionei um `index` na rota da página `Home`, ou seja, quando o `React` renderizar o componente `App` o router entrará em ação e irá renderizar a página da Home.

Como no seu código as rotas estão no componente `About` o `React` irá renderizar o conteúdo do componente `About` + o conteúdo da `rota` que estiver, talvez seja isso que esteja te dando a impressão de que mostra o conteúdo da página anterior.

Para realizar a navegação entre as telas eu gosto de usar o `hook` `useNavigate` pois acho que o código fica mais elegante. Exemplo:

```
const navigate = useNavigate()

<button onClick={() => navigate("home")}>
   Ir para Home
</button>
```

**Observação**: Os exemplos que dei seguem a versão 6 do `react-router-dom`, pelo que pude perceber você está em uma versão mais antiga. Se assim for, o encorajo a atualizar pois a versão 6 está muito boa!

E para que possa se aprofundar segue link da referência que usei:
[react router dom 6](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/overview)

Comment: Salve mano, fiz isso que vc me mandou, coloquei no App, mas apenas o primeiro Route é renderizado, e o resto não tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?                              

const App = () => {
 
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route index path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/Cardapio" element={Cardapio} />
        <Route exact path="/Knowmore" element={Knowmore} />
        <Route exact path="/About" element={About} />
        <Route path="*" element={<p>Página não encontrada</p>} />
      </Routes>   
    </>
  );
};
export default App;

Comment: Então mano, como ele está renderizando suas páginas o comportamente está correto, se vc quer rotear componentes dentro da página vc poderia colocar outro  esquema de rotas, apesar de eu não curtir muito isso eu sei que é possível